# How can I parent separate clothing meshes to different parts of the armature?

Tags: parent

I am attempting to clothe a character in two pieces of clothing that comprise a robe. After parenting the meshes to the armature, when the movement begins the lower "skirt" part deforms up with the hands in an unnatural motion.
I have used the steps:

Select clothing mesh, then armature and parent to empty groups.
Select character mesh then clothing and go to weight paint, assign as transfer weights.

It works well for the upper piece, but the lower portion also follows the arm motion and makes it "flare" forward unnaturally.
I am trying to figure out how to parent the lower portion only the the legs of the armature, but haven't found how or figured it out yet. Any tips or assistance are appreciated.

Comment: You likely need to paint the skirt's weights manually.  Transferring weights typically operates by measuring the closest part of the target.  If the closest part is an arm, rather than a leg, you get arm weights.